# Why am I getting empty results in my RegExp?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to parse my URL into different parts using this RegExp:

```
([\w\\.-]*)
```

Given an example URL http://www.foo.com/bar/baz I get those results from preg_match_all():

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => http
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => www.foo.com
        [5] => 
        [6] => bar
        [7] => 
        [8] => baz
        [9] => 
    )

)
```

It seems that it parses any invalid character into an empty item.
How do I solve this?

Comment: You could also try the parse_url function.

Comment: It's not suitable for URIs. I'm implementing a RESTful dipatching mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `*` you're capturing empty groups - use `+` instead:

```
([\w\.-]+)
```

I assume the extra \ in your RE is because you have it inside a quoted string.

Comment: Re explaining the \... If that is the case, why isnt there one one the \w ?

Comment: +1 `*` will match any count of the preceding expression (including 0), while `+` is "1 or more"

Comment: +1: When using `*`, the character class will match 0 or more times. That means that even if the character class fails, the expression will match an empty string. That's why `:`, `/` and `/` after `http` matched as three empty strings.

Comment: It avoids an infinite loop after matching an empty string by advancing one character.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you want `\\.` ?

In other words, from what you've posted, it looks like you've escaped a backslash instead of the period as you've likely intended to. EDIT: For tidiness, no harm to remove redundant escaping, but this isnt the actual problem [as pointed out by blixt -- thanks].

Highly recommend The Regulator as a regex debugging tool [Though its based on .NET regexes so isnt ideal for PHP work - but the general point that there are tools that will let you identify the basis on which matching is operating]

Still don't understand what you want with the backslashes in the range. Can you post the final regex you use in the question please? And sorry for the distractions that this answer has been!

EDIT: As blixt pointed out, period doesnt act as a metachar as I suggested.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that it does so inside brackets ?

Answer (score 0):

this may do what you want :([\w.-]+|.)
This will match all part of the address.

Comment: I think all he wants to do is to match any string with one or more letters, periods or dashes in it. So the appropriate regex would be: `([\w.-]+)` Adding `|.` would stop the strings from being empty (they would be `":"`, `"/"`, `"/"`, etc.), but they would still be there.

Comment: He wants to break up the html into parts...
That is what I read.

Comment: True, although since he says the empty strings are for "invalid characters", I assumed he didn't want them included in the list of matches.

Comment: Another conclusion could be that all he wants is the domain.

Comment: No, because it matches the directory names too.

Comment: @Aftershock: What you suggest is not what I need.